# node stripe products list return empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, stripe-payments

I'm trying to return all products and plans list from stripe.

However the products list return empty even though there's a `active` product created.

```
function getProductsAndPlans() {
    return Promise.all([
        stripe.products.list({}),
        stripe.plans.list({}),
    ]).then(stripeData => {
       console.log('products', stripeData[0]) <-- this is empty
       console.log('plans', stripeData[1]) <-- this returns plans
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error('Error fetching Stripe products and plans: ', err);
        return [];
    });
}
```

Here are the products from my stripe dashboard:
[image]

Plans get returned:

[image]

But the products list is empty:

[image]

Here's a copy from the stripe doc.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_smkOYa912GSsdfdfDDfByiohm');

const products = await stripe.products.list({
  limit: 3,
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely this is related to the API changes from [2018-02-05](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2018-02-05), when the default behaviour switched from `type=good` to `type=service`, and your account probably having a default API version predating that. Your Product is likely a `type=service` which, as documented, are omitted for Product list requests from older API version by default.

To get the products list request to include the products you're using in the dashboard, you can do one of the following:

1. Explicitly request `service` Products with `stripe.products.list({type: 'service'})` (as noted in the API changelog)
2. Override your default API for [that request](https://stripe.com/docs/api/versioning), with `stripe.products.list({}, {apiVersion: '2018-02-05'})` (or any later version)
3. Upgrade your account [default API version](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#how-can-i-upgrade-my-api)